# Creating Windows in a 'For Loop' (Python)

Tags: python, function, for-loop, tkinter, window

I've been creating a game using Python, and in one of my functions,

```
def Enemy_Party(enemies, party):
        def Sub_Fight(member, enemy, enemies, Prep):
            Prep.destroy()
            Fight(member, enemy, enemies)
        for x in enemies:
            Prep = Tk()
            for y in party:
                button = Button(Prep, text=y.name, command=Sub_Fight(y, x, enemies, Prep)).pack()
            Prep.mainloop()
```

a single window is created, but with nothing in it.  There is no error message, the blank window just sits there.

Yes, I have a function Fight, and it does take four arguments.  Both 'enemies' and 'party' are defined as lists, and both have values within them (I've checked).

On that note, I have two questions:  "Why does the program halt after creating one blank window?" and "Can you define windows in a 'For Loop'?

Let me know if you need any more code, and thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Your snippet does not help much to demonstrate what is happening. Can you provide [minimal working example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) demonstrating the issue you have?

Comment: Also, this  `button = Button(Prep, text=y.name, command=Sub_Fight(y, x, enemies, Prep)).pack()` will result in button being null. The reason is that pack returns null. Maybe this is part of the issue you are having?

Answer (score 3):

The program halts the first time `mainloop` is called, because that's what `mainloop` does -- it doesn't return until you destroy the window.

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to create windows. Every tkinter application needs a *single* instance of `Tk`. To create additional windows you need to create instances of `Toplevel`. You then need to call `mainloop` exactly once.

In your code, replace calls to `Tk` with calls to `Toplevel`, then remove the call to `mainloop` in your function. Presumably you're calling `mainloop` somewhere else in your code after all of the widgets have been created.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you're defining `Tk()` inside a `for` loop. Depending on how many times this loop iterates, you could be creating many instances of *Tk()* when actually you should never create more than one. I would advise creating your window outside of the loop and populating it as you need to using the loop (or whatever else you may decide to use).

Comment: I was actually trying to create multiple windows, one for each 'y in party'.  Is that possible?  If not, can I create a Frame for each 'y'?

Comment: Yeah, you can have multiple windows, but only ONE "master" window (Tk()). Any additional windows need to be defined using Toplevel() instead. I.E., Prep = Toplevel(). You may need to check this, but I'm also pretty sure each window needs a unique name, so they can't ALL be "Prep".

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! .                                                                                                              P.S. The program managed to create two windows named Prep using the loop.

Comment: Ok, nice one. I wasn't sure about the naming thing so good to hear that works fine.